# Prove that the Riemann zeta function has all higher order derivatives.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, riemann-zeta

> I have to prove that the following function has all higher order derivatives.
>   $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(x),\ \ u_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^x},\ \ E=(1,+\infty)
> $$

Here is what I did:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{(k)}=(-1)^k\ln^kn\cdot\frac{1}{n^x}
$$
Therefore, each derivative is continuous on $E$.
Also, I showed that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$ is convergent at some point $x=2\in E$.
The last thing that I have not proved so far is showing that 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u_n(x))^{(k)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\ln^kn\cdot\frac{1}{n^x}$ is uniformly convergent on $E$.

I tried to bound $\left(\frac{1}{n^x}\right)^{(k)}\leqslant\frac{1}{n^{x-k}}$ and show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{x-k}}$ is convergent for $x$ large enough but then I realized that the previous inequality must be met for any $x\in E$. So, I am a bit confused right now.

Comment: The best way to answer this is to use Complex Analysis. The Riemann zeta function is analytic in $Re s>1$ so it has derivatives of all orders. Anyway Complex Analysis is essential for studying  Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false that it is uniformly convergent on $E$.

Nevertheless, you can prove that it converges normally on every $[a,+\infty)$ with $a > 1$. For instance, for $k = 0$,
$$ \forall x \in [a,+\infty),\quad \frac{1}{n^x} \leq \frac{1}{n^a}$$
and $\sum_n 1/n^a$ converges.

It gives that $f$ is continuous on every $[a,+\infty)$, so $f$ is continuous on $E$.

You can do the same thing for all $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Well, and will the continuity of each derivative be enough to prove that $f(x)$ has all higher order derivatives? I tried to prove uniform convergence only because my textbook says it is necessary in order to prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable.

Comment: You can only have uniform convergence on the $[a,+\infty)$, not $E$. It is often the case that you need to avoid the bounds when doing uniform or normal convergence.
The fact that the series of the derivatives of any order converges normally is enough to show that $f$ as all higher order derivative.

Comment: is it divergent for $k\geq 1$?